# Haskell foldl Monad bind

Tags: haskell, fold, state-monad

I got a function

```
move :: Move -> Node -> Maybe Node
```

where I can use my bind monad to obtain a Maybe Node

```
(return n >>= move m)
```

where n::Node and m::Move, but how I can now fold through a list of Moves ([Move])?

I tried to do it with foldl but without success.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin It's actually called `foldM`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have an initial `Node` and a `[Move]` you can use [`foldM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:foldM):

```
moveAll :: Node -> [Move] -> Maybe Node
moveAll startNode moves = foldM (\n m -> move m n) startNode moves
```

or simply

```
moveAll = foldM (flip move)
```